# Evaluating the limit of a certain definite integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, closed-form

> Let $\displaystyle f(x)= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\int_0^x ze^{-(\epsilon)^{-1}\tan^2z}dz$ for $x\in[0,\infty)$.
>
> Evaluate $f(x)$ in closed form for all $x\in[0,\infty)$ and sketch a graph of this function.

Hints, as well as solutions are welcome for this question :-)

Edit:  So far, I have, from substituting $\sqrt{\epsilon}u$ = z,

$\displaystyle f(x)= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_0^{\sqrt{\epsilon}u}  \sqrt{\epsilon}ue^{-(\epsilon)^{-1}\tan^2\sqrt{\epsilon}u}du$

But we can split the integral into two terms, with the first integral equal to zero, by dominated convergence theorem.  I think we only need to look at:

$\displaystyle f(x)= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_0^{a}  \sqrt{\epsilon}ue^{-(\epsilon)^{-1}\tan^2\sqrt{\epsilon}u}du$ +
$\displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_a^{\sqrt{\epsilon}u}  \sqrt{\epsilon}ue^{-(\epsilon)^{-1}\tan^2\sqrt{\epsilon}u}du$

= $$0+\displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_a^{\sqrt{\epsilon}u}  \sqrt{\epsilon}ue^{-(\epsilon)^{-1}\tan^2\sqrt{\epsilon}u}du$$

(I'm not sure if integrating away from the origin helps much, to be honest.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:**

I wanted to give a special thanks to @robjon for his insightful comments.

---

We first observe that $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}e^{-\tan z/\epsilon}=0$ unless $z=\ell \pi$, $\ell$ an integer.  Therefore, all of the "action" of the integration will take place over intervals around $\ell \pi$.  So, let's first see what is happening for $0<x<\pi/2$.

---

In the spirit of [Laplace's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method), we have for $0<z<\pi/2$, $\tan^z =z^2+O(z^4)$ and thus for $0<x<\pi/2$

$$\begin{align}
\epsilon^{-1/2}\int_0^xze^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}dz&\sim\epsilon^{-1/2}\int_0^xze^{-z^2/\epsilon}dz\\\\
&=\epsilon^{-1/2}\left.\left(-\epsilon^{-z^2/\epsilon}\right)\right|_{z=0}^{z=x}\\\\
&=\epsilon^{1/2}\left(1-e^{-x^2/\epsilon}\right)
\end{align}$$

which clearly goes to zero as $\epsilon\to 0$.

---

Next, we observe that the integration around singularities of the tangent function pose no challenge.  Thus, for a general $(L-1)\pi<x<L\pi$, and $\delta >0$ we can write

$$\begin{align}
\epsilon^{-1/2}\int_0^x ze^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}dz&=\epsilon^{-1/2}\sum_{\ell=0}^{L-2}\left(\int_{\ell \pi+\delta}^{(\ell+1)\pi-\delta}ze^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}dz+\int_{(\ell+1)\pi-\delta}^{(\ell+1)\pi+\delta}ze^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}dz\right)\\\\
&+\epsilon^{-1/2}\int_{(L-1)\pi+\delta}^{x}ze^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}dz \tag 1\\\\
\end{align}$$

We observe that in $(1)$ the only integrals that will contribute in the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ are those around integer multiples of $\pi$.  Thus, we have for $(L-1)\pi<x<L\pi$ and $\delta>0$

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\epsilon^{-1/2}\int_0^x ze^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}dz&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon^{-1/2}\sum_{\ell=0}^{L-2}\left(\int_{(\ell+1)\pi-\delta}^{(\ell+1)\pi+\delta}ze^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}dz\right) \tag 2\\\\
\end{align}$$

We proceed to evaluate the integrals in $(2)$.  To that end we have

$$\begin{align}
\epsilon^{-1/2}\int_{(\ell+1)\pi-\delta}^{(\ell+1)\pi+\delta}ze^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}dz &=\epsilon^{-1/2}\left(\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}ze^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}dz+(\ell +1)\pi\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}e^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}dz\right)\\\\
&=(\ell +1)\pi\epsilon^{-1/2}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}e^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}dz\\\\
&\sim (\ell +1)\pi\epsilon^{-1/2}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}e^{-z^2/\epsilon}dz\\\\
&= (\ell +1)\pi\int_{-\delta/\epsilon^{1/2}}^{\delta/\epsilon^{1/2}}e^{-z^2}dz\\\\
&\to (\ell +1)\pi^{3/2}
\end{align}$$

Summing over $\ell$ we find for $(L-1)\pi<x<L\pi$

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\epsilon^{-1/2}\int_0^xze^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}dz=\frac{L(L-1)\pi^{3/2}}{2}$$

One final note concerns the case in which $x=L\pi$.  For that case, we see that we need to add one more integral, namely

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\epsilon^{-1/2}\int_{L\pi-\delta}^{L\pi}ze^{-\tan^z/\epsilon}&=L\pi\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-z^2}dz\\\\
&=\frac12 L\pi^{3/2}
\end{align}$$

Thus, for $x=L\pi$ we have

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\epsilon^{-1/2}\int_0^xze^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}dz=\frac{L^2\pi^{3/2}}{2}$$

Putting it all together we have

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\epsilon^{-1/2}\int_0^xze^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}dz=
\begin{cases}
\frac{L(L-1)\pi^{3/2}}{2},&(L-1)\pi<x<L\pi\\\\
\frac{L^2\pi^{3/2}}{2},&x=L\pi
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Really cool solution, @Dr.MV.  Can I ask a follow-up question?  How'd you get the -2z^2?

Comment: Such a cool solution, @Dr.Mv.  I was convinced that the answer couldn't possibly be zero, since that'd be trivial.  I'm going to sleep and re-do this problem in the morning.  Thanks so much!!  Have a great night :-)

Comment: Hi @Dr.MV, actually, do we have to worry about the blow-ups from the tan function? +infinity is fine, but if it's -infinity, we get $e^{\infty}$ .  Or is tan^2 always non-negative?

Comment: Yes, it's non-negative - the integrand doesn't blow up.  Sorry, I'm just in a state of shock that the answer is equal to zero, I guess.

Comment: Ok, got it - I will redo this problem along with the version with $\epsilon^{-1}$ to see what I integrate and come up with.  Thanks, @Dr.MV!  Good night!

Comment: This only works for $x\lt\pi$. The interesting part comes when $x\ge\pi$.

Comment: The part of your answer where you get $2z^2+O(z^6)$ is garbled. Are you claiming that $\tan^2(z)=2z^2+O(z^6)$? If so, that seems to be problematic as $\tan^2(z)=z^2+O(z^4)$.

Comment: In the final answer, you need to have $(L-1)\pi\le x\lt L\pi$; otherwise, there may be multiple choices for $L$ given a particular $x$.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, of course. I'll edit again.

Comment: You note that $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0} e^{-\tan^2(x)/\epsilon}=0$. However, what is needed is $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0} \frac1{\sqrt\epsilon}e^{-\tan^2(x)/\epsilon}=0$ for $x\ne0$, and that $\frac1{\sqrt\epsilon}e^{-\tan^2(x)/\epsilon}$ is uniformly bounded in $\epsilon$ for $x$ away from $0$ (the last is so that we can use Dominated Convergence).

Comment: @robjon I did note that and for purpose of gaining an understanding of where the "action" is in the integral.  I don't see that this note is inappropriate.

Comment: Hi @Dr.MV, thanks so much for this!!  I think I finally understand this problem now :-)

Comment: @LebronJames You're quite welcome.  And special thanks goes to Robjon for showing the way forward!

Answer (score 6):

Consider what happens on an interval $[n\pi-\frac\pi2,n\pi+\frac\pi2]$. Let $x=\tan(z)$ and $u=x/\sqrt{\epsilon}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac1{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\int_{n\pi-\frac\pi2}^{n\pi+\frac\pi2}e^{-\tan^2(z)/\epsilon}\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac1{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+\epsilon u^2}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\\[6pt]
&=\sqrt\pi\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
For all $\epsilon\gt0$, we have
$$
\frac1{\sqrt\epsilon}e^{-\tan^2(z)/\epsilon}\le\frac{|\cot(z)|}{\sqrt{2e}}\tag{2}
$$
Thus, for any $\lambda\gt0$, [Dominated Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) says
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac1{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\int_{n\pi-\frac\pi2}^{n\pi+\frac\pi2}\big[|z-n\pi|\ge\lambda\big]e^{-\tan^2(z)/\epsilon}\,\mathrm{d}z=0\tag{3}
$$
where $[\cdot]$ are [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Combining $(1)$ and $(3)$ gives
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac1{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\int_{n\pi-\frac\pi2}^{n\pi+\frac\pi2}\big[|z-n\pi|\lt\lambda\big]e^{-\tan^2(z)/\epsilon}\,\mathrm{d}z=\sqrt\pi\tag{4}
$$
Limits $(3)$ and $(4)$ tell us that $\frac1{\sqrt\epsilon}e^{-\tan^2(z)/\epsilon}$ is an approximation of
$$
\sqrt\pi\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta(z-n\pi)\tag{5}
$$
where $\delta(z)$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Thus,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac1{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\int_0^xz\,e^{-\tan^2(z)/\epsilon}\,\mathrm{d}z
=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\displaystyle\pi^{3/2}\,\frac{\lfloor x/\pi\rfloor^2+\lfloor x/\pi\rfloor}2&\text{if }x\not\in\pi\mathbb{Z}\\
\displaystyle\pi^{-1/2}\,\frac{x^2}2&\text{if }x\in\pi\mathbb{Z}
\end{array}\right.}\tag{6}
$$
The plot would look something like

[image]

Comment: Mathematica concurs using `f[x_,e_]:=1/Sqrt[e]NIntegrate[z Exp[-Tan[z]^2/e],{z,0,x},WorkingPrecision->20]`

Comment: @Dr.MV: The proof above shows that on $[n\pi-\frac\pi2,n\pi+\frac\pi2]$, $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac1{\sqrt\epsilon} e^{-\tan^2(z)/\epsilon} =\sqrt\pi\delta(z-n\pi)$$ so that on the whole real line $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac1{\sqrt\epsilon} e^{-\tan^2(z)/\epsilon} =\sqrt\pi \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta(z-n\pi)$$ which is given in line $(5)$. Thus, integrating against $z$ we get the sum of $\sqrt\pi\,n\pi$ for each point $z=n\pi$ in the domain of integration. If the domain of integration ends at $n\pi$, then due to symmetry, we get half the value normally contributed at that point.

Comment: Hi @robjohn, I've been studying your solution all day today and finally have some meaningful questions to ask:  1)  we know the integrand goes to zero, if $tan^2$ is positive, since then the exponential factor of the integrand goes to zero exponentially fast - the 1/$\sqrt{\epsilon}$ does no harm.  But wherever $tan^2$ is equal to zero, then the integrand blows up - since there is only a z/$\epsilon$ term in the integrand.  But you showed that it is *at* the point of blow-ups of the integrand, namely when $sin^{2}$ is zero, which occurs at integer multiples of $\pi$,

Comment: that there is a nonzero contribution from the integration - $\sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: do I have the right idea?  so whichever x we are fixing as our upper limit, we are just counting the number of n$\pi$'s in our integration domain, and then multiplying $\sqrt{\pi}$ with consecutive integers (integration against z, as you called it), z = 1,2,3,...

Comment: and you showed that any z that is a positive distance away from n$\pi$ -- so, z not  of the form n$\pi$-- gives a zero integral, by dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: I don't understand the piecewise defined function -- is it just the consecutive integers formula?

Comment: So, I'm just trying to make sense of it all.  Thank you so much for posting this solution, @robjohn!! :-)

Comment: @LebronJames: I am out getting dinner. I will address your questions as soon as I can.

Comment: Ok, enjoy!! Very exciting solution.  I think I almost understand it all - you are indeed using the sum of consecutive integers formula, taking into account that x may not be an integer, so you're using the floor function to account for this case.  :-)

Comment: @robjohn How did you arrive at inequality $(2)$ for all positive $\epsilon$?  Take $\epsilon=4$ (yes, I know that we let $\epsilon \to 0$, but the bound states for all $\epsilon>0$), $z=\pi/3$ and we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}e^{-\tan^2z/\epsilon}=\frac12e^{-3/4}\approx. 0.236183$, while $\frac{1}{e\tan^z}=\frac{1}{3e}\approx. 0.122626$.  So, the inequality seems to fail.  Just curious ... how did you arrive at it?

Comment: Hi @robjohn, I just have one question remaining for this problem:  was the motivation to consider the interval you suggested coming from the fact that $tan^2$ is $\pi$ - periodic, so that perhaps ...if we knew the contribution of the integration over one period of the function, we pretty much know the integration over the whole real line?  (I think the exponential function, composed with $tan^2$, is still periodic with the same minimum period, $\pi$.)  Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames: on $\big[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\big]$, $\frac1{\sqrt\epsilon}e^{-\tan^2(x)/\epsilon}$ is a family of approximations to $\sqrt\pi$ times the Dirac delta function. Since $\tan^2(x)$ has a period of $\pi$, on $\mathbb{R}$, $\frac1{\sqrt\epsilon}e^{-\tan^2(x)/\epsilon}$ is an approximation to $\sqrt\pi$ times the sum of Dirac delta functions translated to $x=n\pi$. Thus, on an interval containing a neighborhood of $n\pi$, the integral of $\frac1{\sqrt\epsilon}f(x)e^{-\tan^2(x)/\epsilon}$ tends to $\sqrt\pi\,f(n\pi)$.

Comment: @LebronJames: on an interval ending at $n\pi$, the integral of $\frac1{\sqrt\epsilon}f(x)e^{-\tan^2(x)/\epsilon}$ tends to $\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\,f(n\pi)$. In the case at hand, $f(x)=x$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: Note that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\alpha e^{-\alpha \tan^2(x)}=e^{-\alpha\tan^2(x)}(1-\alpha\tan^2(x))$. Thus, the maximum occurs when $\alpha=\frac1{\tan^2(x)}$; that is, when $\alpha e^{-\alpha\tan^2(x)}=\frac1{e\tan^2(x)}$.

Comment: But that isn't the right-hand side.  It is $\sqrt{\alpha}e^{-\alpha \tan^2(x)}$.  So, it appears that this is the source of error.

Comment: @robjohn It doesn't change the thrust of your development, but the bound you want to establish dominated convergence is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}e^{-\tan^2x/\epsilon}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2e\tan^2x}}$$However, doesn't the DC theorem require the dominating function be integrable?  Neither $\cot^2x$ nor $|\cot x|$ are integrable on any interval containing a singularity.  So, does that not invalidate the reasoning here?

Comment: @Dr.MV: Oops... that is the bound, but that works as well. All we are trying to show with dominated convergence is $(3)$ and for that $|x|\ge\lambda$. Since $\frac1{\sqrt\epsilon}e^{-\tan^2(x)/\epsilon}\le\frac{\cot(\lambda)}{\sqrt{2e}}$, the integrands are bounded by $\frac{\cot(\lambda)}{\sqrt{2e}}$ on $|x|\ge\lambda$ and $|x|\lt\frac\pi2$ so the dominating function **is** integrable (bounded on a bounded set).

Comment: I don't want to nit pick, but you need an absolute value sign on the cotangent for the bound.

Comment: Indeed. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: What would a sketch of the graph look like?  I have a set of dots that are monotone increasing.  In between these dots, I have a line going through the real axis (to show zero contribution away from n$\pi$...and then near n$\pi$ I connect the line on the real axis with the dot - to show a sharp spike upwards, and then sharply downwards back to the real axis (f(x) = 0).  Then repeat for the other (higher) dots (point masses).  So, this sketch would also be in line with what you described, @robjohn - I am just essentially sketching out a *family* of Dirac delta functions on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: @LebronJames: between each pair of consecutive integers, the limit is constant. At each integer, the limit is exactly half way between the values in the neighboring intervals. So the graph is horizontal lines between the integers and points half way between at the integers.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much @robjohn :-)

Answer (score 1):

For small $\epsilon$, 
$\tan^2(\sqrt{\epsilon} u )
\approx \epsilon u^2$, 
so the integral is of 
approximately
$\sqrt{\epsilon}u e^{-u^2}$ 
which can be integrated.

Comment: Thanks for the cool observation, @martycohen! :-)