# Question about the dirac $\delta$-function

Tags: dirac-delta

I have a basic question about the dirac $\delta$-function based on the beginning of Chapter 1 of [these notes](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/ivan.wilde/notes/gf/gf.pdf).

The dirac $\delta$-function can be defined heuristically as the function that is $0$ everywhere except as $x = 0$, where it is $\infty$.

But formally, this is not the definition of the functional (since it's not a function).  Here is my question:

> Since $\delta$(x) is not defined for each $x$, how can we talk about the product $(f(x)-f(0))\delta(x)$?  The author says this is identically $0$.  Why?  If we are using the heuristic definition of $\delta$, then when $x \neq 0$, $\delta(x) = 0$ so the product is $0$, and if $x = 0$, then we get $(f(0) - f(0))\cdot \infty$, but who is to say this is equal to $0$?  If $0 \cdot \infty$ always equaled $0$, then under this heuristic definition, we should have $\int \limits_{\Bbb R} \delta(x) \,dx = \int \limits_{\Bbb R - \{0\}} \delta(x) \,dx + \int \limits_{ \{0\} } \delta(x)\,dx = 0 + 0 \cdot \infty = 0$, but this integral is by definition equal to $1$.  But even so, what if we aren't using the heuristic definition?

Comment: To avoid confusions the distributions like $\delta$ is to be understood as a linear functionals on the test function space, i.e. only *inside an integral*. One can give a precise definition of $g(x)\delta(x)$ as a distribution if $g$ is *continuous*. It is just a symbol, not a point-wise multiplication. Like $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not a fraction.

Comment: @A.G. What do you mean only inside an integral?  I was under the assumption that $\delta$ as a functional is *by definition* $<\delta, \phi> := \phi(0)$ for a test function $\phi$.  If that's true, it would agree with the idea that we cannot talk about $\delta(x)$ in an integral because it's not a function.  (Then again, we define $\int \limits_{\Bbb R} \phi(x) \,dx = 1$, so I guess we can talk about it inside of an integral....)

Comment: It is just a matter of definition. There are many definitions of an integral, the most general is exactly a linear functional. It is not very important. What is important is that a distribution is not a point-wise function, it is a result of an action on the test functions.

Comment: @A.G. Yes, exactly.  The symbolic notation is only used formally because the linear Dirac Functional shares many properties of the integral.  And the notation is the point that can be confusing to those applying it.

Comment: @A.G. : $<\delta_a,f> = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{f(a+\epsilon) + f(a-\epsilon)}{2}$, this a linear form, no need that $f$ be a test function. when studying the Fourier or Laplace transform in 1st,2nd or 3rd year of college, we prefer to not ear about distributions, we just do a special case for $\delta$. we learn for example that integration by parts works with $\delta$ (the dirac being integrated).

Comment: @reuns A.G. is trying to address the OP's question and not impose on others anything.  ;-))

Comment: and we can talk about integrals of distributions against correct functions because convergent integrals of correctly parametred functions are linear forms too. this is what Schwartz invented : integral on $[a;b]$ of $f\times g$ where $f$ is variable = linear form

Comment: @reuns : Please: Write $\langle\delta_a,f\rangle$, not $<\delta_a,f>$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Another rigorous definition of $\delta (x)$ is in terms of a point measure $
\mu _{0}(dx)$ with unit strength centered in $x=0$, so $\int \mu _{0}(dx)=1$
. Then, for $f(x)$ continuous in $x=0$,
$$
\int dxf(x)\mu _{0}(dx)=f(0)
$$
which equals
$$
f(0)\int dx\mu _{0}(dx)=f(0)
$$

Comment: @Urgje What exactly does $\displaystyle \int \,dx f(x) \mu_{0}(dx)$ mean?  You are taking one integral with respect to two measures?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The first $dx$ should not be present.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> See [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413689/dirac-delta-integral-with-delta-infty-cdot-e-infty/1413826#1413826), where I provided a Primer on the Dirac Delta.

The heuristic statement $\delta(x)(f(x)-f(0))=0$ means that for each test function $f$, the functional $D[f(x)-f(0)]=0$, where $D[\cdot]$ is the Dirac Delta functional.

We write the functional for $D$ formally as

$$D[\cdot]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)[\cdot]dx \tag 1$$

But the right-hand side of $(1)$ is not an integral.  Rather, it shares many of the same properties with integrals and is therefore useful notation.  But it is only notation.

So, for a test function $f(x)$, we have

$$D[f(x)]=f(0)$$

and therefore

$$D[f(x)-f(0)]=f(0)-f(0)=0\tag 2$$

Finally, we interpret $(2)$ formally and write

$$\delta(x)(f(x)-f(0))=0$$

---

Text books that heuristically discuss the Dirac Delta will often give the curiously nonsensical point-wise definition of $\delta(x)$

$$\delta(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,&x\ne 0\\\\
\infty,&x=0
\end{cases}
$$

which obviously is meaningless even with the additional condition that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)\,dx=1$.

This "hand-waving" description can be made rigorous by defining a family of functions $\delta_n(x)$ with the properties that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\delta_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,&x\ne 0\\\\
\infty,&x=0
\end{cases}
$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta_n(x)\,dx=1 \tag 3$$

One may then write, $\delta(x)\sim \lim_{n\to \infty}\delta_n(x)$ with the interpretation provided by $(3)$.  Examples of such families of functions include the pulse function

$$\delta_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
n/2,&-\frac{1}{n}\le x\le \frac{1}{n}\\\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

and the Gaussian function

$$\delta_n(x)=\frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-n^2x^2}$$

In this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335591/divergence-of-vecf-frac-hat-mathrmrr2/1335781#1335781), I discussed the regularization used in potential theory for the $\mathscr{R}^3$ Dirac Delta $\delta(\vec r)$.  There, the Dirac Delta is written

$$\begin{align}
\delta(\vec r)&\sim \lim_{a\to 0}\delta_{a}(\vec r)\\\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0} \frac{3a^2}{4\pi(r^2+a^2)^{5/2}}
\end{align}$$

where $\lim_{a\to 0}\int_{\mathscr{R}^3}f(\vec r)\,\delta_{a}(\vec r)\,dV=f(0)$.

And finally in this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353404/evaluating-the-limit-of-a-certain-definite-integral), I analyze the family of functions $\delta_{\epsilon}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\,\epsilon}}e^{-\tan^2(x)/\epsilon}$ that describes the "train" of Dirac Deltas

$$\sum_{\ell =-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-\ell \pi)\sim \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\,\epsilon}}e^{-\tan^2(x)/\epsilon}$$

Comment: Well, what does $\int \limits_{\Bbb R} \delta(x) \,dx$ mean formally?  How are we integrating something that is not a function?  We define this integral to be $1$, but what does the integral mean?

Comment: It is not an integral.  It is a functional that takes functions and maps them into numbers.

Comment: The formal notation is useful because the linear functional shares many of the same properties of the integral.

Comment: I'm very confused.  $<\delta, \phi(x)>$ is defined to be $\phi(0)$, and from your answer it sounds like writing $\int \limits_{\Bbb R} \delta(x) \phi(x)\,dx$ is just alternate notation for $< \delta, \phi(x)>$ and doesn't really mean the integral.  Then why do we *define* $\int \limits_{\Bbb R} \phi(x) \,dx = 1$?  We shouldn't have to.  It should follow directly from the definition of $<\delta, f(x)>$, since $<\delta, f(x)> = f(0)$, and if $f(x)$ is the constant function $1$, then $f(0) = 1$, so $<\delta, 1> = 1$.

Comment: @user46944 You are exactly correct.  $D[1]=1$ follows as you noted!  Well done.

Comment: Ok, I have one more question.  Now that I understand your explanation, how does it follow from your explanation that heuristically we define $\delta(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \neq 0 \\ \infty & x = 0 \end{cases}$ with $\int \limits_{\Bbb R} \delta(x) \,dx = 1$?  I understand the second condition, but how does one get the first condition from the definition of this functional?

Comment: @user46944 Great question.  When one regularized the distribution, one has an actual family of functions $g_n(x)$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty}g_n(x)=0$ for $x\ne 0$ and $g_n(0)\to \infty$ and such that for all test function $f$, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int g_n(x)f(x)dx=0$.

Comment: So, $\delta(x) \sim \lim_{n\to \infty}g_n(x)$

Comment: So you're saying we can find actual functions $g_{n}$ such that they each integrate to $1$, and if we consider their integral against any test function $\phi(x)$, then the limit of these integrals can be thought of as the integral against the limiting function, which isn't really a function?  I'm just trying to see if I understand what you are saying.  You wrote $\delta(x) ~ \lim_{n \to \infty} g_{n}(x)$.  Is that because actually $\lim_{n \to \infty} <g_{n}, \phi> = \phi(0)$?

Comment: @user46944 Yes! You are correct and apparently truly have it now.  Great job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26223/discussion-between-dr-mv-and-user46944).

Comment: Thank you for your help!  No need for further discussion.  You are great at explaining. :)

Comment: You're welcome!  It has been my pleasure.  And thank you for that nice compliment.  I'm at home recovering from surgery 3 and a half weeks ago.  You just made my weekend!  Much appreciative

Comment: @Dr.MV - nice answer, that required another vote up! Hope you recover soon!

Comment: @Johannesvaks Wow! Thank you so much.  I cannot begin to tell you how much that means!  My 4th surgery in 14 months

Comment: I'd say the right hand side of 1 is an integral, a Riemann stieltjea integral with a particular step function as integrator.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Yet, it is not an integral.  It is a functional.  See the primer for which I have provided a link.

Comment: @Dr.MV yes, I read it, but I still fail to see why can't we say $$\int_{\Bbb R} f \delta(x)dx :=\int_a^b f d\alpha$$ where $\alpha(x)=1$ for $c\geq 0$ and $-1$ otherwise.

Comment: $\delta(x)$ is not a function, and it is not an integral.

Comment: @FelixMarin Felix, thank you for the nice comment!  -Mark

Answer (score 4):

To say that $(f(x) - f(0)) \delta(x)$ is identically $0$ means that if we integrate $(f(x) - f(0)) \delta(x)$ against any test function, we get the same thing as if we integrate $0$ against that test function.  Let $\varphi$ be a test function.  Then
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(x)\Big( (f(x)-f(0)) \delta(x) \Big) \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Big(\varphi(x)(f(x)-f(0))\Big) \delta (x)\, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \left. \varphi(x)(f(x)-f(0)) \vphantom{\frac 1 1} \,\right|_{x=0} = \varphi(0)(f(0)-f(0)) = \cdots
\end{align}

Comment: Well, at the end of the day, as Dr. MV said, the integral notation is just that: notation.  $\delta(x)$ is just notation for the linear functional taking a test function $\phi(x)$ to $\phi(0)$.  Then for any test function $\phi(x)$, $\phi(x) - \phi(0)$, under this functional, this function is sent to $\phi(0) - \phi(0) = 0$.  Thus, $\delta(x)(\phi(x) - \phi(0))$, which is just notation for the image of $\phi(x) - \phi(0)$ under the linear functional $\delta$, is just $0$.

Comment: How did you get that $\displaystyle \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Big ( \phi(x)(f(x) - f(0)) \Big ) \delta(x) \,dx = \phi(x)(f(x) - f(0))$ (evaluated at $x = 0$)?

Comment: @user46944 : You would need to show that $x\mapsto\varphi(x)(f(x)-f(0))$ is itself a test function.  That would depend on knowing something about what sort of function $f$ is.  Then use the fact that for every test function $\psi$ we have $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(x)\delta(x)\,dx = \psi(0)$.  That is simply the definition of the Dirac delta function $\delta$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Well $f(x)$ was already a test function in the notes, so $\phi(x)(f(x) - f(0))$ is a test function if $\phi$ is.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers testify, there are many useful viewpoints on "what's really happening" with Dirac's $\delta$. Also, there is the chronic confusion of whether "formal" means that something is really true/correct for trivial reasons, or, rather, that it is a suggestive heuristic that perhaps cannot be made legitimate but is useful.

The most specific response I have to the original question is simply about *multiplying* (compactly supported) distributions $u$ by *smooth* functions $f$ to obtain another *distribution*: $f\cdot u$ is the distribution defined by $(f\cdot u)(\varphi)=u(f\cdot \varphi)$ where $f\cdot \varphi$ is the pointwise multiplication, producing another test function.

Thus, in the case at hand, for any $f$ vanishing at $0$ (e.g., produced by replacing $f$ by the function $x\to f(x)-f(0)$), we have $(f\cdot \delta)(\varphi)=\delta(f\cdot \varphi)=(f\cdot\varphi)(0) = f(0)\cdot u(0)=0$. That is, such $f\cdot \delta$ is the $0$ *distribution*, not the *number* $0$.

As some answers noted, $\int_{\mathbb R}\delta(x)\cdot 1\;dx$ can be construed as $\langle \delta,1\rangle$. Rather than disclaiming the integral expression by saying it's "just formal", why not say that it is to be interpreted as the extension to the pairing between distributions and test functions of the pairing of test functions and test functions by integrating-against. It is the extension-by-continuity of that pairing, using the weak-dual topology on distributions, after all.

There is some precedent for taking the viewpoint that "formally meaningless" integrals are in fact precise, meaningful extensions-by-continuity of pairings that *are* literal integrals on dense subspaces. Fourier transform and inversion on $L^2(\mathbb R)$ are examples of this: the integral itself only makes sense on $L^1$, but after proving Plancherel, we extend-by-isometry/continuity, and still write the integral, even though it is not *literally* that integral.

There is also the possibility of thinking of "multiplication by" $\delta$ as an *operator* mapping test functions to distributions, as suggested in some other answers. But here one might consider writing $\delta\otimes \delta$ when it's meant as an operator. Indeed, for two distributions $\alpha,\beta$, the operator $\alpha\otimes \beta$ is $(\alpha\otimes\beta)(\varphi)=\beta(\varphi)\cdot \alpha$. These are rank-one operators given by the "smallest" possible Schwartz kernels...

Answer (score 2):

Dirac's $\delta$ is a distribution, not a function per se. Formally $\langle\delta,f\rangle=f(0)$. A common choice for the space where these things live is the dual of the Schwartz functions.
In physics the manipulation of these things is less rigorous in the notation. Since for some function spaces (like $L^2$) all linear functional into $\mathbb{R}$ are also functions ($\langle f,g\rangle=\int fg$) the notion of a generalized function is extended and the notation kept.

A more rigorous treatment is also to define $\int \delta f=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow\infty}\int f \rho_\epsilon$ where $\rho$ is a $C^\infty$ function with compact support around zero, and $\rho_\epsilon=\rho(r/\epsilon)/\epsilon$

$\delta g$ would be the distribution defined by $\langle\delta  g,f\rangle=f(0)g(0)$, so if $g(0)=0$, then $\delta g$ is always zero.

Comment: Dirac is not a function, Are you Sure ?

Comment: @Cardinal The dirac $\delta$ is not a function because no function satisfies the two properties we want it to satisfy: that it is $0$ everywhere except at $x = 0$, where it is $\infty$, and that the integral of it over $\Bbb R$ equals $1$.  No real valued function satisfies this, so it can't be a function.

Comment: @user46944 so you think $\frac{1}{x}$ is not a function as matter of the $\infty$

Comment: @Cardinal $1/x$ is a function, on the domain $\Bbb R - \{0 \}$.  It is undefined at $x = 0$, though.

Comment: So what is the difference? ! sounds weird !

Comment: what about this: ?
$$\delta(x)=\frac{d}{dx}u(x)$$

Now, if $u$ is the step function, how a linear transform could bring about  a distribution ?

Comment: @Cardinal Well, is not a function. The definition that it is 0 everywhere and $\infty$ in 0 is of another function which does not fulfills the properties of the $\delta$ "function", but it is used as a non-rigorous explanation of its properties.

Answer (score 2):

One can define
$$
\delta(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
|x| > \epsilon &:& 0\\\\
|x| \le \epsilon &:& \displaystyle \frac{1}{2\epsilon}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Whence
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(x) =
\int_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon} \frac{ 1 }{2\epsilon} dx = 1.
$$
and
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \delta(x) =
\int_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon} \frac{ f(x) }{2\epsilon} dx = f(0).
$$