# Definition of the Dirac Delta function gives Sin converging to zero at infinity.

Tags: convergence-divergence, dirac-delta

It would seem that (one) definition of the Dirac Delta function implies  the Sin function converges to zero at infinity.

The Dirac Delta function can be defined as:

$\delta(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}dk$

Which follows from the Fourier transform of the delta function.  The delta function evaluated at x=1 is zero by definition so:

$\delta(1) = 0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ik}dk$

But this would mean:

$0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ik}dk = \frac{1}{2\pi i }e^{ik} |_{-\infty}^{\infty}= \frac{1}{2\pi i }[cos(k)+isin(k)] |_{-\infty}^{\infty} = \frac{1}{2\pi i }[2isin(k)] |_{\infty} = \frac{1}{\pi }sin(\infty)$

So:

$sin(\infty) = 0$

What am I doing wrong here?  Is it incorrect to assume this is a statement of convergence at infinity?

Comment: $\delta(x)$ is not a function in a conventional sense and $\delta(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}dk$ is a *formal* expression that can't be evaluated the way you did.

Comment: The Dirac Delta is not a function.  See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413689/dirac-delta-integral-with-delta-infty-cdot-e-infty/1413826#1413826) and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372858/question-about-the-dirac-delta-function/1372870#1372870) for primers.