# Need help finding the particular part of Green's function for an inhomogeneous differential equation with inhomogenous boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, greens-function

What I am trying to find is also referred to as $\tilde{G}$ and I was trying to verify what @Gonçalo had found for it in their answer to [MY QUESTION](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4769847/solving-a-differential-equation-using-greens-function-where-the-forcing-term-is). I'm using the exact same inhomogeneous differential equation with inhomogeneous boundary conditions (BCs) from the question, but I'm focusing on a single part of the problem which is, again, obtaining $\tilde{G}$ as it is defined in the answer. I can't figure out exactly where I'm screwing up and I'm beginning to suspect that my error is systematic because I've gone over the work several times now and I don't see any silly mistakes.

Here is the definition of $\tilde{G}$ and its conditions as was provided by @Gonçalo:

$\tilde{G}_{xx} = \delta(x-x')$ is satisfied by

$\tilde{G} = \cases{\frac{1}{2}(x+1)(x'-1) & x<x' \\ \frac{1}{2}(x-1)(x'+1) & x>x'}$ which is verified using the following conditions: $\text{(i)} \tilde{G}(±1,x′)=0, \text{(ii)} \tilde{G}(x′+0,x′)=\tilde{G}(x′−0,x′), \text{and (iii)} \tilde{G}_x(x′+0,x′)−\tilde{G}_x(x′−0,x′)=1$

---

My work starts here:

$$\text{starting with homogeneous eqn for }\tilde{G}:\\ \tilde{G}_{xx} = 0 \\ \text{solve: }\int\int\tilde{G}_{xx} = 0 \rightarrow \tilde{G}_{xx} = Ax+B \\ \text{from (i), the solution satisfying BC1: } A_1(-1) + B_1 = 0 \rightarrow B_1 = A_1 \\ \text{from (i), the solution satisfying BC2: } A_2(1) + B_2 = 0 \rightarrow B_2 = -A_2 \\ \text{gives 2 solutions: }\tilde{G} = \cases{A_1x+A_1 = A_1(x+1) \\ A_2x-A_2 = A_2(x-1)} \\ \text{apply (ii): } A_1(x'+1) = A_2(x'-1) \\ A_1 = A_2 \frac{(x'-1)}{(x'+1)} \\ \text{apply (iii): } A_1 - A_2 = 1 \rightarrow A_1 = 1 + A_2 \\ \text{plug into (ii) and solve for constants: } 1+A_2 = A_2\frac{(x'-1)}{(x'+1)} \\ \frac{1+A_2}{A_2} = \frac{(x'-1)}{(x'+1)} \rightarrow \frac{1}{A_2} = \frac{(x'-1) - (x'+1)}{(x'+1)} \rightarrow \frac{1}{A_2} = -\frac{2}{(x'+1)} \\ A_2 = -\frac{1}{2}(x'+1) \\ A_1 = 1+A_2 = \frac{2}{2} - \frac{1}{2}(x'+1) \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}(-x'+1) \\ A_1 = -\frac{1}{2}(x'-1)$$

This gives: $$\tilde{G} = \cases{-\frac{1}{2}(x+1)(x'-1) & x<x'\\ -\frac{1}{2}(x-1)(x'+1) & x>x'}$$

I've gone over the work several times already, and I can't figure out how to get rid of this pesky negative sign, so I I'm starting to think the error I'm making is systematic and I don't know what step it is that I'm messing up or glossing over. I'm thinking my inequality might have been set up wrong such that it would instead be $$\tilde{G} = \cases{-\frac{1}{2}(x+1)(x'-1) & x>x'\\ -\frac{1}{2}(x-1)(x'+1) & x<x'} \\ \text{negative sign flips the inequality: } \tilde{G} = \cases{\frac{1}{2}(x+1)(x'-1) & x<x'\\ \frac{1}{2}(x-1)(x'+1) & x>x'}$$. I don't actually understand how the inequality is supposed to be set up to begin with, so I'm thinking that could be it. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You are using the indices $1$ and $2$ for the regions $x<x'$ and $x>x'$, respectively. Therefore, the equation after "apply (iii)" should be $A_2-A_1=1$.

Comment: @Gonçalo Oh that's right! You just helped me realize the physical meaning of this form of what you had written: $\big(\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^+} \frac{\partial^{n-1}G}{\partial x^{n-1}}\big) - \big(\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^-} \frac{\partial^{n-1}G}{\partial x^{n-1}}\big) = 1$. The first term takes the derivative as $x$ goes to $x_0^+$ meaning that (if we're on a number line) we're approaching $x_0$ from the right, and from the piecewise definition of $\tilde G$, we would take the derivative of the part defined on $x>x_0$. Conversely we would do the same for the part defined on $x<x_0$.

Comment: @Gonçalo When I see some of this notation come back up from Calculus I, I often feel intimidated and lose my head dealing with something that would otherwise be trivial. I ended up psyching myself out on this one. Thanks again!