# What is the laplace transform of $\delta(t-\pi /6)\sin (t)$

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta

> What is the laplace transform of $\delta(t-\pi /6)\sin (t)$

I know that $L\{\delta(t-\pi/6) \}=e^{-s\pi/6}$
I also know that $L\{\sin (t) \}=1/(s^2+1)$

I also know that $L\{(u(t-\pi/6)f(t-\pi/6)\}=e^{-s\pi/6}F(s)$ where $F(s)=L\{f(t)\}$

Comment: if $f(t)$ is continuous then $\delta(t-a) f(t) = f(a) \delta(t-a)$ ... did you ever draw what looks like a $\delta$ distribution ??

Comment: $\delta (t-t_0) =0 $ when $t\ne t_0$. So I'm assuming it will be $\infty$ at $t_0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Laplace transform is by definition $$ \int_0^{\infty}\exp(-st)\delta(t-\pi /6)\sin (t)dt=\sin(\frac{\pi}{6})\exp(-s\frac{\pi}{6})=(1/2)\exp(-s\frac{\pi}{6})$$

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain how did you integrate that?

Comment: By definition of Dirac delta integrating over all possible values of t the Dirac delta only selects $t=\frac{\pi}{6}$ as it would be always zero otherwise.

Comment: Wouldn't an integral over a single point be $0$?

Comment: It is not an integral over a single point, you are integrating over all possible values of $t$, namely $(0,\infty)$ but then you have the delta $\delta(t-\frac{\pi}{6}$ which is non zero only if $t=\pi/6$ (by definition) that basically selects only this particular value of $t$ ( as it is the only value that would give a non zero contribution to the integral).

Answer (score 2):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413689/dirac-delta-integral-with-delta-infty-cdot-e-infty/1413826#1413826) and [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372858/question-about-the-dirac-delta-function/1372870#1372870), I provided primers on the Dirac Delta.

Using the "sifting property" of the Dirac Delta, for any suitable test function $\phi(t)$, we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-t')\,\phi(t)\,dt=\phi(t') \tag 1$$

Now, let $\phi(t)=e^{-st}\sin(t)u(t)$ and $t'=\pi/6$.  Then from $(1)$ we find

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \delta(t-\pi/6)\,e^{-st}\sin(t)\,dt&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-\pi/6)\,e^{-st}\sin(t)u(t)\,dt\\\\
&=e^{-s\pi/6}\sin(\pi/6)u(\pi/6)\\\\
&=e^{-s\pi/6}\sin(\pi/6)\\\\
&=\frac12 e^{-\pi s/6}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!