# Using the Dirac delta function to find the density of point masses/charges

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates, dirac-delta

`Here is an example from a textbook:`

> Suppose there is a unit charge or unit mass at the point $(x,y,z)=(-1,\sqrt{3},-2)$; then in rectangular coordinates, the density is 
>   $$\rho=\delta(x+1)\,\delta(y-\sqrt{3})\,\delta(z+2)\tag{1}$$
>   In cylindrical coordinates the point is $(r,\theta,z)=\left(2,\frac{2\pi}{3},-2\right)$, so in cylindrical coordinates the density is
>   $$\rho=\frac{\delta(r-2)\,\delta\left(\theta -\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\delta(z+2)}{r}\tag{2}$$ In spherical coordinates, the point is $(r,\theta,\phi)=\left(2\sqrt{2},\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)$, so in spherical coordinates the density is
>   $$\rho=\frac{\delta(r-2\sqrt{2})\,\delta\left(\theta -\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)\delta\left(\phi-\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)}{{r^2}\sin\theta}\tag{3}$$

When I substitute the point $(x,y,z)=(-1,\sqrt{3},-2)$ into equation $(1)$ I get a density of unity as expected.

When I substitute the point $(r,\theta,z)=\left(2,\frac{2\pi}{3},-2\right)$ into equation $(2)$ I get a density of $$\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\ne 1}$$

When I substitute the point $(r,\theta,\phi)=\left(2\sqrt{2},\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)$ into equation $(3)$ I get a density of $$\color{red}{\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\ne 1}$$

I thought that choice of coordinate system is irrelevant since all coordinate systems you use will always lead you to the same result.

So why are the parts marked $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ not equal to unity?

---

### EDIT:

In response to the comments below, since we

> "cannot evaluate the Dirac Delta as if it has a value at a point; it
>   is not a function"

From $(1)$; Is it plausible to write $$\rho=\delta(0)\,\delta(0)\,\delta(0)$$ at the point $(x,y,z)=(-1,\sqrt{3},-2)$?

Notice that I did not *evaluate* the Dirac Delta, but I did *substitute* the coordinates in.

In other words; Is substitution allowed but evaluation **not** allowed?

Comment: You cannot evaluate the Dirac Delta as if it has a value at a point; it is not a function.  See [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413689/dirac-delta-integral-with-delta-infty-cdot-e-infty/1413826#1413826) and [THIS ONE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372858/question-about-the-dirac-delta-function/1372870#1372870) for primers.

Comment: So basically your question is why are there the factors in the denominators?

Comment: @Korf No, it's okay I understand why the denominators are present

Comment: @Blaze Ok. I'd say the answer more or less lies in what Dr. MV wrote. The important thing that is invariant under coordinate change is $\int \delta(x) f(x) \mathrm d x$. This is the invariant value, not the denominator. This also enforces the change of the denominator and your red inequalities, roughly speaking.

Comment: @Dr.MV Please see my edited post, thank you.

Comment: @BLAZE Since the Dirac Delta is not a function, it makes no sense to ask "what is the value of $\delta(x)$? for any $x$.  And this does not exclude $x=0$.  That is, $\delta (0)$ has no value.  The notation $\delta(x)$ has meaning only as a distribution.  If $f(x)$ is a sufficiently smooth function with compact support, then the functional $\langle f,\delta_0\rangle =f(0)$.  Continued ...

Comment: This is often written as $\langle f,\delta_0\rangle =\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x)\,dx=f(0)$.  But the integral notation represents neither an integral in the sense of Riemann nor an integral in the sense of Lebesgue.  It is a functional that maps the test function $f(x)$ into the number $f(0)$.  I hope this is clearer.

Comment: @Dr.MV You have given an excellent explanation and for that I am very grateful. Just to be completely clear; It is __not__ correct to write $\rho=\delta(0)\,\delta(0)\,\delta(0)$ since $\delta(0)$ is undefined; Is that correct? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $Q=\iiint \rho \, dV$

In Cartesian:
$$Q=\iiint \rho(x,y,z) \, dx \, dy \, dz=1$$

In Cylindrical:
$$Q=\iiint \rho(r,\theta,z) \,  r\, dr \, d\theta \, dz=1$$

In Spherical:
$$Q=\iiint \rho(r,\theta,\phi) \, r^2\sin \theta \, d\theta \, dr \, d\phi=1$$

Hence for **point** charge:

\begin{align*}
  \rho(x,y,z) &= \delta (x-x_{0}) \, \delta (y-y_{0}) \, \delta (z-z_{0}) \\
  \rho(r,\theta,z) &= \frac{1}{r}
  \delta (r-r_{0}) \, \delta (\theta-\theta_{0}) \, \delta (z-z_{0}) \\
  \rho(r,\theta,\phi) &= \frac{1}{r^2\sin \theta}
  \delta (r-r_{0}) \, \delta (\theta-\theta_{0}) \, \delta (\phi-\phi_{0}) \\
\end{align*}