# How can I prove $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \space \text{Im}\frac{1}{x+i \epsilon}=-\pi\delta(x)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, dirac-delta

I want to show that:

> $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \space \text{Im}\frac{1}{x+i \epsilon}=-\pi\delta(x)$$

This is my attempt:

1. I assumed that $\text{Im}$ stands for the imaginary part. Therefore, $$\frac{1}{x+i \epsilon} \cdot \frac{x-i \epsilon}{x-i\epsilon}=\frac{x-i\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}=\frac{x}{x^2+\epsilon^2}-i \left (\frac{ \epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2} \right ) \implies\Im(z)=-\frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{\epsilon}+\epsilon}$$
2. Taking the limit: $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} -\frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{\epsilon}+\epsilon}=0$$

But this would mean that $$\implies0=-\pi \delta(x) $$

However, this equality can't be true because:

$$\delta(x)=\begin{cases}\infty, \space \space\space x=0 \\ 0, \space \space \space x \not= 0 \end{cases}$$

which would mean that at $x=0$ the equality $0=-\pi \delta(x)$ is not true. What am doing wrong?

Comment: What should you actually have at $0$?

Comment: You took the limit to infinity, rather than the limit to zero.

Comment: @Neil Whoops. Major mistake. Let me fix that.

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä I am not sure what you mean. Is your question: What is the value of $$\frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{ \epsilon} +\epsilon}$$ at $\epsilon=0$?

Comment: Well, you show that the limit is $0$ if $x\neq 0$, this is consistent (I'm omitting to comment on the typo where you write $\varepsilon\to \infty$ instead of $\varepsilon\to 0$). But your whole argument, from 2. onwards, implicitly assumes $x\neq 0$: treat the case $x=0$ separately, now.

Comment: Consider evaluating the limit separately for the cases $x = 0$ and $x \not= 0$

Comment: @ClementC. Ohh I see! At $x=0$ $$ \implies \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} -\frac{1}{\epsilon}= -\infty$$

Thank you! :)

Comment: You need to look at the function's properties inside an integral.  Simply saying the delta function is 0 at $x \neq 0$ and $\infty, x=0$ isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @Paul So you are saying my argument doesn't make sense? Are you saying I need to use properties like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x)dx=1$ etc.?

Comment: Indeed the pointwise limit is quite irrelevant (and I do not know why some users send you on this road), rather you are supposed to show that, for every suitable test function $f$, $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_\mathbb Rf(x)\frac{-\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}dx=-\pi f(0).$$ Any idea to show this?

Comment: (To react to the above: I (incorrectly, it seems) assumed $\delta(x)$ was used as a concise notation to express what the OP wrote, not in the distribution sense -- and that $\pi$ was the writer of the exercise being facetious. My bad.)

Comment: @Did Maybe this is a really stupid question but how does my initial statement: $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \space \text{Im}\frac{1}{x+i \epsilon}=-\pi\delta(x)$$ 

translate to : $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_R f(x) \frac{-\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}dx=-\pi f(0)$$

I just don't see the connection. In other words, how would I know that I have to show the satement you mentioned above?

Comment: Because this is the only rigorous definition of the Dirac distribution $\delta$. What were you trying to prove before I explained that?

Comment: @Did Thank you for your help. I will try to read and understand the answer and links provided by Dr. MV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413689/dirac-delta-integral-with-delta-infty-cdot-e-infty/1413826#1413826) and [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372858/question-about-the-dirac-delta-function/1372870#1372870), I provide primers on the Dirac Delta.

For any smooth test function $\phi$, we have for any $\nu >0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|\phi(x)-\phi(0)|<\nu$ whenever $|x|<\delta$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\text{Im}\left(\frac{1}{x+i\epsilon}\right)\,dx&=-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{|x|\ge \delta} \phi(x)\left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\,dx-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\delta}^\delta \phi(x)\left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\,dx\\\\
&-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\delta}^\delta \phi(x)\left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left(\int_{-\delta}^\delta (\phi(x)-\phi(0))\left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\,dx-\phi(0)\int_{-\delta}^\delta \left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\,dx\right)\\\\
&=-\pi \phi(0)-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\delta}^\delta (\phi(x)-\phi(0))\left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\,dx\\\\
\end{align}$$

Note that we have for any $\nu>0$

$$\left|\int_{-\delta}^\delta (\phi(x)-\phi(0))\left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\,dx\right|\le 2\nu \arctan(\delta/\epsilon)\le \pi \nu $$

Therefore, for any smooth tests function $\phi$, we find

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\text{Im}\left(\frac{1}{x+i\epsilon}\right)\,dx=-\pi \phi(0)$$

This is equivalent to the statement that

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\text{Im}\left(\frac{1}{x+i\epsilon}\right)\sim -\pi \delta(x)$$

in the sense of a regularization of the Dirac Delta.

Comment: Maybe overkill, but what about using the DCT to show that $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x)\frac{\varepsilon}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}dx = \pi \phi(0)$$? Starting with $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x)\frac{\varepsilon}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(\varepsilon u)\frac{du}{u^2+1}$$ for $\varepsilon > 0$ (with "$u=\varepsilon x$" and then applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem. (It looks more direct, even though it invokes a less elementary theorem.)

Comment: @ClementC. No overkill at all, on the contrary this might be the most natural way of thinking about the whole shebang if you have some notions of probability... And it works beautifully.

Comment: Yes, that works after the substitution interestingly.  One needs an indicator function as part of the integrand in that case.

Comment: Really great answer. It will take me some time to work through it and through the links you have provided. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Did Thanks. Glad I did not stay astray up to the very end...

Comment: @bluemoon You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Just a quick question. Can you recommend any "easy" and "accessible" textbooks that treat this in detail? I am quite new to this stuff and a bit shaky when it comes to the notation.

Comment: [Here](http://www.amazon.com/Generalized-Functions-I-Properties-Operations/dp/0122795016) is one reference to Generalized Functions.  I embedded links in the answers that I referenced in this post.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks! Have a nice day! :)