# Integration of Dirac Delta Function from -3 to 0

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, dirac-delta

I'm learning about Dirac Delta functions, and I have a question about when one of the bounds is 0.

An example I'm working on is $\int_{-3}^{0}\,dx\,\delta(x-1)$.

How would I evaluate this at 0?

Would it just be undefined?

Thanks!

Comment: Whatever the definition, the result is $0$ because $1$ is not into the interval of integration $[-3,0]$.

Comment: Yes of course. If you meant $\int_{-3}^0 \delta(x) dx$ then It depends on your definition of $\delta$. So what is your definition ? A common one is $\int_a^b \delta(x) f(x) dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_a^b \frac{1_{|x| < \epsilon}}{2 \epsilon} f(x) dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2 \epsilon}\int_{[a,b] \cap [-\epsilon,\epsilon]} f(x)dx$.

Comment: @Bye_World and this definition is consistent only for $\phi(x)$ continuous at $x= 0$ and $A$ an open set

Comment: I think JeanMarie's answer makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you really meant $\int_{-3}^0 \delta(x-1)dx$ then it is $0$ under your definition, since $\int_{-3}^0 \delta(x-1)dx = \int_{(-4,-1)} \delta(x)\phi(x)dx$ with $\phi(x) = 1$ continuous at $x=0$

Comment: $\int_{a}^{b}\delta\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{f}\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = \,\mathrm{f}\left(0\right)\left\{\left[a < 0 < b\right] -\left[b < 0 < a\right]\right\}$.

Answer (score 1):

> **In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413689/dirac-delta-integral-with-delta-infty-cdot-e-infty/1413826#1413826) and [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372858/question-about-the-dirac-delta-function/1372870#1372870), I provided primers on the Dirac Delta.**

---

The notation $\int_a^b f(x)\delta(x-c)\,dx$ is interpreted to mean the functional $\langle fp_{ab},\delta_c\rangle$.

Here, $p_{ab}$ is the "rectangular pulse" function, $p_{ab}(x)=u(x-a)-u(x-b)$, and $u$ is the unit step (or [Heaviside Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)) where

$$u(x)=\begin{cases}1&,x>0\\\\0&,x<0\end{cases}$$

> Note that there are various conventions for the value $u(0)$.

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b f(x)\delta(x-c)\,dx&=\langle fp_{ab},\delta_c\rangle\\\\
&=\begin{cases}f(c)&,c\in(a,b)\\\\0&,c\notin [a,b]\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

In the case at hand, we have $a=-3$, $b=0$, and $c=1$.  Therefore, we have

$$\int_{-3}^0 f(x)\delta(x-1)=0$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And Happy Holidays! -Mark