# Reference of delta function as a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Any one know the reference of direct delta function as a measure, I need a graduate math rigorous version not physical one.

Comment: You might want to look at a course of Distribution Theory. There you will find the theorem indicating that the set of distributions of order $0$ can be identified to the set of measures. See also my answer where I explained the link between the delta distribution and the delta measure here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710573/proving-int-limits-infty-infty-deltaxdx-1/3762252#3762252

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the Dirac-measure?
$$
\delta_{x_0}(A) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{, if }x_0 \in A \\
0 & \text{, if }x_0 \notin A
\end{cases}
$$
Obviously, $\Omega$ is some set, $x_0 \in \Omega$ and $A\in \Sigma$ for some $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma \subseteq 2^\Omega$.

If you use $\delta_{x_0}$ to integrate, it works like the delta distribution:
$$
\int_{\Omega} f~\mathrm{d}\delta_{x_0} = f(x_0)
$$
for some measurable $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

This is because of $\delta_{x_0} (\Omega \setminus \lbrace x_0 \rbrace) = 0$ and
$$
\int_{\Omega} f~\mathrm{d}\delta_{x_0} = \underbrace{\int_{\Omega \setminus \lbrace x_0 \rbrace} f~\mathrm{d}\delta_{x_0}}_{=0} + \int_{\lbrace x_0 \rbrace} f~\mathrm{d}\delta_{x_0} = f(x_0)\delta_{x_0}(\lbrace x_0 \rbrace) = f(x_0)
$$
by definition of the integral.

Comment: Yes, but more detailed reference with respect to delta function. I am using \delta as measure and distribution at the same and hope to know more.

Comment: @DiyiLiu I have edited my post

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Is there any books particular for this? I want to know more about it.