# Question about dirac Delta function

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\delta(x)$ denote a Dirac Delta function on $R$.

Then, I know that 
$$\delta(x) = 0 \text{ if } x \neq 0$$
and

$$\int_R \delta(x) f(x) dx = f(0)$$

Then, since $\delta(x)$ is zero everywhere except at $0$, it seems to me that

$$\int_{(-\epsilon, \epsilon)} \delta(x) f(x) dx = f(0)$$

for any $\epsilon >0$, but since $\delta$ is not a "function", how does one jusfity this?

Comment: Treat "$\delta(x) dx$" as a measure that measures a function by taking the value at a point (in this case $0$), then this makes sense.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг If I treat it as a measure, what is the measurable space that it acts on? It is the set of ALL functions on $R$?

Comment: The way to make this rigorous is using the theory of distributions, if you think delta function as a limit of some distributions you can prove that these are equivalent.

Comment: @RafaelWagner True, using an approximation via convolution with mollifiers.Also the measure space is the set of all subsets of $\mathbb R$, the measure is : zero if the set doesn't contain $1$, and one otherwise. Using the definition of function integration, one arrives at the formula that you have given.

Comment: EDIT: I meant zero if the set doesn't contain $0$ above.

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413689/dirac-delta-integral-with-delta-infty-cdot-e-infty/1413826#1413826) and [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372858/question-about-the-dirac-delta-function/1372870#1372870), I provided primers on the Dirac Delta.**

---

The notation $\int_a^b f(x)\delta(x-c)\,dx$ is interpreted to mean the functional $\langle fp_{ab},\delta_c\rangle$.

Here, $p_{ab}$ is the "rectangular pulse" function, $p_{ab}(x)=u(x-a)-u(x-b)$, and $u$ is the unit step (or [Heaviside Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)) where

$$u(x)=\begin{cases}1&,x>0\\\\0&,x<0\end{cases}$$

> Note that there are various conventions for the value $u(0)$.

Therefore, with $a=\epsilon$, $b=-\epsilon$, and $c=0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon f(x)\delta(x)\,dx&=\langle fp_{-\epsilon\,\epsilon},\delta_0\rangle\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p_{-\epsilon\,\epsilon}(x)f(x)\delta(x)\,dx \\\\
&=f(0)p_{-\epsilon\,\epsilon}(0)\\\\
&=f(0)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Very elegant result.

Comment: @rafaelwagner Thank you.  Much appreciative.  -Mark

Comment: Am I right that $p_{ab}$ is essentially a characteristic function of the interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: The term "characteristic function" has a variety of meanings.  If you mean the indicator function, then the answer is "yes."

Answer (score 0):

The "function" that you speak of is not actually a function, but a mathematical object called a "distribution" or a generalized function.

To remain brief, we can talk about linear functionals over a function space, i.e. the set of all functions $T$ such that $T : C^\infty_0 \to \mathbb{C},$ for example.  Here, $C^\infty_0$ is the set of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support.  The delta function is one such linear functional.  To be called a distribution only requires a few more properties (such as continuity).  Using the suggestive notation 
$$ \delta(f(x)) = f(0) \text{ as } \langle \delta, f \rangle = f(0)$$
then perhaps this bracketed notation behaves like an inner product, which would mean
$$ \langle \delta, f \rangle = \int \delta(x)f(x)\; dx = f(0).$$

However, as you pointed out, this integral doesn't make sense in the genuine function sense, and hence we stick with $\delta$ being a function that maps a given *test function* to its value at the origin.