# Integration by part of a dirac function : something I don't understand

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Consider the following integral :

$$ \int_{\tau'}^{\tau''} d\tau f(\tau) \frac{d}{dt}[\delta(t-\tau)] $$

We can put out of the integral the derivative with respect to time $t$ and thus we have :

$$ \int_{\tau'}^{\tau''} d\tau f(\tau) \frac{d}{dt}[\delta(t-\tau)]=\frac{d}{dt}[f(t)] $$

But I also have :

$$ \frac{d}{dt}[\delta(t-\tau)] = -\frac{d}{d \tau}[\delta(t-\tau)]$$

And if I plug this I have :

$$ \int_{\tau'}^{\tau''} d\tau f(\tau) \frac{d}{dt}[\delta(t-\tau)] = - \int_{\tau'}^{\tau''} d\tau f(\tau) \frac{d}{d\tau}[\delta(t-\tau)]$$

And after doing an integration by part I will have the same result as before **plus** a surface term.

So the two way of computing the integral don't give the same results.

Where is the problem in what I have done ?

Comment: Maybe the surface term is zero?

Comment: @yahoo in a general case I don't see why it would be zero. I would have $f(\tau')\delta(t-\tau')-f(\tau'')\delta(t-\tau'')$. For $t=\tau''$ it is not $0$ for example

Comment: The Dirac Delta is NOT a function.

Comment: Since we are assuming $\tau'<t<\tau''$, and inasmuch as the Dirac Delta, $\delta(t-\tau)$ has compact support on $\{t\}$, then we have in the sense of distributions $\delta(t-\tau')=\delta(t-\tau'')=0$.  This last expression hold also when $t>\tau''$ and $t<\tau'$.

Answer (score 1):

> **In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413689/dirac-delta-integral-with-delta-infty-cdot-e-infty/1413826#1413826) and [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372858/question-about-the-dirac-delta-function/1372870#1372870), I provided primers on the Dirac Delta.**

---

The notation $\int_{\tau'}^{\tau''} f(\tau)\delta(\tau-t)\,d\tau$ is interpreted to mean the functional $\langle \delta_t, fp_{[\tau',\tau'']}\rangle$.

Here, $p_{[\tau',\tau'']}$ is the "rectangular pulse" function, $p_{[\tau',\tau'']}(x)=u(x-\tau')-u(x-\tau'')$, and $u$ is the unit step (or [Heaviside Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)) where

$$u(x)=\begin{cases}1&,x>0\\\\0&,x<0\end{cases}$$

---

> Note that there are various conventions for the value $u(0)$.

---

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\tau'}^{\tau''} f(\tau)\delta(\tau-t)\,d\tau&=\langle \delta_t,fp_{[\tau',\tau'']}\rangle\\\\
&=\begin{cases}f(t)&,t\in(\tau',\tau'')\\\\0&,t\notin [\tau',\tau'']\end{cases}\\\\
&=f(t)p_{[\tau',\tau'']}(t)\tag1
\end{align}$$

If $t=\tau'$ or if $t=\tau''$, then the value of the functional $\langle\delta_t, fp_{[\tau',\tau'']}\rangle$ is not well-defined.  That is to say that as a function of $t$, the functional is (jump) discontinuous at $t=\tau'$ and $t=\tau''$.

---

> Note, if $g(\tau)=f(-\tau)$, then the notation $\int_{\tau'}^{\tau''} f(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau$ is interpreted to mean the functional $\langle \delta_{-t},gp_{[-\tau'',-\tau']}\rangle$, which by virtue of $(1)$ shows that $$\int_{\tau'}^{\tau''} f(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau=\int_{\tau'}^{\tau''} f(\tau)\delta(\tau-t)\,d\tau$$.

---

Next, we have the notation

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\langle \delta_t ,fp_{[\tau',\tau'']}\rangle&=\langle \frac{d}{dt}\delta_t ,fp_{[\tau',\tau'']}\rangle\\\\
&=\int_{\tau'}^{\tau''}f(\tau)\frac{d}{dt}\delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau\\\\
& =\begin{cases}f'(t)&,t\in (\tau',\tau'')\\\\0&,t\notin [\tau',\tau'']\end{cases}\\\\
&=f'(t)(p_{[\tau',\tau'']})(t)
\end{align}$$

where the derivative is undefined at $t=\tau'$ and $t=\tau''$ due to the jump discontinuities.

---

> If we interpret the derivative of the Heaviside function as the Dirac Delta distribution, then we can extend the definition of $\frac{d}{dt}\langle \delta_t ,fp_{[\tau',\tau'']}\rangle$ to include the jumps at $t=\tau'$ and $t=\tau''$.  We then have in distribution
>
> $$\langle \frac{d}{dt}\delta_t ,fp_{[\tau',\tau'']}\rangle=f'(t)p_{[\tau',\tau'']}(t)+f(\tau')\delta(t-\tau')-f(\tau'')\delta(t-\tau'')$$
>
> which can be converted notationally to read
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{\tau'}^{\tau''}f(\tau)\frac{d}{dt}\delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau=f'(t)p_{[\tau',\tau'']}(t)+f(\tau')\delta(t-\tau')-f(\tau'')\delta(t-\tau'')}\tag 2$$

---

Inasmuch as the distributional derivative is defined by

$$\langle \delta'_{t},fp_{\tau',\tau''}\rangle =-\langle \delta_{t},\left(fp_{\tau',\tau''}\right)'\rangle $$

we see that in distribution

$$\begin{align}
\langle -\delta'_{t},fp_{\tau',\tau''}\rangle&=\langle \delta_{t},\left(fp_{\tau',\tau''}\right)'\rangle\\\\
&=f'(t)p_{[\tau',\tau'']}(t)+f(t)\frac{d}{dt}p_{[\tau',\tau'']}(t)\\\\
&=f'(t)p_{[\tau',\tau'']}(t)+f(\tau')\delta(t-\tau')-f(\tau'')\delta(t-\tau'')
\end{align}$$

> Hence, we have notationally
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{\tau'}^{\tau''}\left(-\frac{d}{d\tau}\right)\delta(t-\tau)f(\tau)\,d\tau=f'(t)p_{[\tau',\tau'']}(t)+f(\tau')\delta(t-\tau')-f(\tau'')\delta(t-\tau'')}\tag 3$$

---

Comparing $(2)$ and $(3)$, we arrive at the equality that

$$\langle \frac{d}{dt}\delta_t ,fp_{[\tau',\tau'']}\rangle=\langle -\delta'_{t},fp_{\tau',\tau''}\rangle=f'(t)p_{[\tau',\tau'']}(t)+f(\tau')\delta(t-\tau')-f(\tau'')\delta(t-\tau'')$$

or using the alternative notation

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{\tau'}^{\tau''} f(\tau)\left(-\frac{d}{d\tau}\right)\delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau=\int_{\tau'}^{\tau''}f(\tau)\frac{d}{dt}\delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

The "surface term" is 0 due to the delta. That is, the term from the integration by parts
$$
\left [ f(\tau) \delta(t - \tau) \right ]_{\tau'}^{\tau''}
= f(\tau'')\delta(t-\tau'') - f(\tau')\delta(t-\tau') = 0
$$
and you recover the expression obtained through the other method. In the case where $t=\tau''$ or $t=\tau'$, it depends on how you define the Dirac-delta, in a physics sense or in the sense of distributions. Often in physics one defines
$$
\int_0^a f(t) \delta(t) \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{2} f(0)
$$
for example, but then the concept of $\frac{\mathrm{d} \delta}{\mathrm{d} t}$ is another matter altogether.

Comment: I don't get why it is $0$. If I take $t=\tau''$ I will still have the first contribution ?